# Possible formats and file names in GitHub main repository page, instead of README.md?

Tags: github

In GitHub, a repository's main page, under the list of files, by default, there's a compiled view of a `README.md` markdown file.

I like it. But, can this be a reStructuredText file, or an HTML file, instead?

What's the support? What is the logic there? What can I use?

Answer (score 8):

A Github readme needs to be called readme to be picked up. GitHub supports the extensions listed below, you can read more details on the [markdown readme file](https://github.com/github/markup/blob/master/README.md).

- [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/): .markdown, .mdown, .mkdn, .md
- [Textile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_%28markup_language%29): .textile
- [RDoc](http://rdoc.sourceforge.net/): .rdoc
- [Org mode](http://orgmode.org/): .org
- [Creole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creole_(markup)): .creole
- [Mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Formatting): .mediawiki, .wiki
- [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html): .rst
- [AsciiDoc](http://asciidoc.org/): .asciidoc, .adoc, .asc
- [Plain Old Documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl/pod/perlpod.pod): .pod

Answer (score 1):

The following are my findings so far.

I'm also waiting for an answer from GitHub.

### Possible formats

[John C's, answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/66928/54435) regarding the formats leads us to the [GitHub `markup`](https://github.com/github/markup) library, which answers the formats question.

### Possible names

It seems that the name, excluding the extension, must be `README`.

Seems to be case–insensitive.

Case of the extension does seem to matter.